# in grails when I run I got this error

Tags: grails

```
:: Before findByName ::
2018-02-16 12:08:28.544 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.p.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl        : HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.iconn
ect.grails.mis.model.BaseReportCriteriaCommand, setter method of property: groupByList
2018-02-16 12:08:28.560 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.p.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl        : HHH000091: Expected type: java.util.ArrayList, actual v
alue: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentList
2018-02-16 12:08:28.709 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
strong text
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `groupByList` in `BaseReportCriteriaCommand` from `ArrayList` to `List`.